# Long jump with a selector decided at run time in x86

Tags: x86, x86-64, nasm

I'm trying to perform a long jump in assembly so that I can load a descriptor from the GDT into the segment register CS. I realize I can do this by hard coding the address like this (`jmp 0xAB:some_label`) but I don't want to hard code the address like that. I see that the jump instruction has the following format (`jmp ptr16:32`) but I'm not quite sure what is the syntax for ptr16? I tried `AX,[AX], BX, [BX]` but nothing worked. I tried searching everywhere for how to perform such operation to no avail. So could someone provide the proper syntax for long jumping to an address that is specified at runtime (either in memory or in register)?

Comment: `jmp ptr 16:32` is [Jump far, absolute, address given in operand](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp), so it is the hard-coded `jmp 0xab:some_label` you were already using. Presumably what you really want is a a memory operand.

Comment: I see. And what is the syntax for the memory operand? [AX] does not seem to work as I mentioned.

Comment: Before you start messing around with far `jmp`, you should understand the basics of 16-bit mode like the restctions on which addressing modes are valid.  [NASM x86 16-bit addressing modes](//stackoverflow.com/q/12474010).  But you tagged this x86-64 and 64-bit, so 16-bit address-size isn't available at all.  Why would you think that the CPU could load a new 80-bit CS:RIP from `[BX]`?  Or are you trying to enter 64-bit mode from 16-bit mode where `[BX]` makes sense?

Comment: It's the latter. I'm trying to write my own kernel and I'm in the process of switching from 32-bit to 64-bit. As to why I was using 16 is because that's what I thought the jmp instruction wanted when it specified ptr16 bit.

Comment: Not sure why this was marked as duplicate since the other question is asking about far call no jmp. and the syntax, which is what I'm asking for is not the same.

Comment: The syntax for far call and far jump are exactly the same.

Comment: Note that that question and this one seem to be asking about 16 bit mode. If you are asking about entering 64 bit mode, which is necessarily done from 32 bit mode, not 16 bit mode, you may want to clarify the question or write a new one.